# Is $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus V(f)$ homotopy equivalent with a "large ball complement"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $f\in\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and let $V(f)$ denote the vanishing locus. Is it true that for large enough $N$, there is a homotopy equivalence
$$\mathbb{C}^n\setminus V(f)\simeq B(0,N)\setminus V(f),$$
where $B(0,N)=\{|x|<N\}$.

Comment: This is more generally true for semialgebraic subsets of $\mathbf R^n$ and follows from the fact that they are conical at infinity (see Bochnak, Coste, Roy: Real algebraic geometry, Corollary 9.3.7, p. 225)

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Thank you for the answer, I will look up the statement in the book.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman This does indeed answer my question. If you want you write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK, thank you. No need to write it as an answer, I think.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman It is recommended to convert your comment to an answer in this situation, so that the question does not remain on the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @NeilStrickland OK then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more generally true for semialgebraic subsets of $\mathbf R^n$ and follows from the fact that they are conical at infinity (see Bochnak, Coste, Roy: Real algebraic geometry, Corollary 9.3.7, p. 225)